# Rails Gem Installation Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Bundle install won't work if i write following in my gem file

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

i got following errors

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
In Gemfile:
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  activerecord (~> 4.0.0) ruby

rails (= 4.1.2) ruby depends on
  activerecord (4.1.2)
```

but when i install this gem from terminal like

```
gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
```

I got following sucess message

```
Fetching: activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.1.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.1.0
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference from installing a gem via bundler and installing a gem directly. When using Bundler, Bundler will resolve the gem dependencies within the context of any other gem included in the `Gemfile`. Therefore, if both gem A and B depend on C, but they depend on two different versions, Bundler will complain.

In your case, `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` depends on `activerecord` (~> 4.0.0) which means any release 4.0.x, whereas you are using Rails 4.1.2 that depends on `activerecord` 4.1.2.

`activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` and `rails` have the same dependency, but the version mismatches. You either need to downgrade Rails (not recommended), or upgrade the `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` dependency. You may need to contact the maintainer of `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`, or fork the library.

Answer (score 1):

You say you put this:

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

But the bundle statement says this:

```
In Gemfile:
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
...
```

Did you really put this in your Gemfile?

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Because the latest `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` supports AR 4.1.x.  You could try `bundle up activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`, to get the latest, or specify `'~> 4.1'` in your Gemfile.